# UEFI boot - not dual

Tags: installation, 13.04, boot, uefi

So, I made the mistake of buying a laptop with this uefi. I have no interest in dual booting Windows, I just want to install Ubuntu without the need of a degree in quantum physics. Right now I can only get my laptop to end the installation, but at the next boot it will open up the setup bios and won't go further... Is there a guide to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Did you look at this : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

Did you disable secure boot in BIOS?
These links might help you.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2160313